# Running a WinForms program in WinPE 10 with NetFX

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, winpe

I created a WinPE 10 image with most of the optional packages (WMI, scripting, NetFX(.Net 4.5),etc... ) The WinPE image runs great.  I created a simple WinForm program to execute.  On my main computer it runs fine.  When I run it in WinPE the program doesn't error out but does nothing.  I created it in Visual Studio Professional 2013.  I've been looking if any extra steps are needed Visual Studio for making it work in WinPE 10.  WinPE images I'm great at but I'm still new to Visual Studio's.  Here are the reference I'm using, been wondering if that maybe it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Comment: does WinPE support the same assemblies that WinForms does..? perhaps if you could show some code maybe you need to do some proper error trapping / handling.. but from what you posted.. it does no good did you check MSDN to see if .net version 4.5.x is supported as well?

Comment: Yes, WinPE 10 supports .Net 4.5, and I do know you have to add the WMI component first.  Here's the MSDN
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824926.aspx
I think it's something I'm don't know about what exactly is supported or some step I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, I just remade the WinPE image from scratch again and it works.  I suspect I forgot the language component for either WMI or NetFX.